# Geometrical solution to a search problem

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Given:

- an infinite grid
- a robot that can move to adiacent cells
- you have available  up(), down(), left(), right() and distanceToDestination() functions
- destination coordinates and robot coordinates are unknown

To do

- find an algorithm to move the robot to destination asap

I already have a solution which searches on one axis and then changes, which solves the problem, but I am trying to improve and find a better algorithm. And I was trying to approach the problem from a geometrical perspective.

Triangulation

- calculate distance for current point A = dA
- generate a new point and get dB
- generate a new point and get dC

So I have 3 (or more) distances to a specific point in a plane. Can I calculate the position of the destination point relative to the origin?

I think there is only one mathematical solution for 3 circles intersection with center in A,B,C and radius dA, dB, dC, but I would like a confirmation from you if this solution works.

Comment: If the destination and robot coordinates are unknown, how is the robot supposed to know he reached his destination?

Comment: @Raskolnikov The robot knows the distance to its destination.

Comment: Why not minimize along one coordinate first, then the other? Is the distance Euclidean?

Comment: Ah, I see, that's what the distancetoDestination() function does.

Comment: @cooper.hat I already have that algorithm, but that one it has too many steps in my opinion. I want another one which finds the destination faster. I assume that the distance is Euclidean, but the problem was actually not precise. As this is only an algorithm we can assume is Euclidean and not Manhattan or other step kind of distance.

Comment: Well, given 3 points along one axis, you can figure out the minimizing coordinate (assuming Euclidean). Then one more step will give the direction to minimize along the other coordinate. So you waste at most 2 steps?

Comment: I guess you need to tell us what the cost is? No matter what, you need to move one step at a time, so the minimum number of moves is the Manhattan distance/

Comment: My question is only if with the 3 distances and 3 relative points can I detect the destination point relative to one of the known points. Maybe I should remove the original question

Comment: Assuming no error and different sampling points, yes

Comment: @chubakueno can you be more specific in an answer please?

Comment: My point basically was: given three cuadratic equations for two variables, the first pair generates a pair of solutions, assuming no errors in measures and that you are taking samples from different locations(this would generate two exactly equal equations). The third one eliminates the ambiguety between both solutins and takes only one as valid

Comment: I was given a similar problem, where the only difference was that the distance to destination is the minimal number of units the robot has to move horizontally or vertically. -- The solution the OP accepted is something like http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ejcqurmclbr but in my case that would really translate to something like http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e7ojkc0ou3h .

Comment: Probably larger values are needed. http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ej6slpmmkdd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting at $(0,0)$ let $A$ be the distance to the target.
Move right one step. Let $B$ be the distance to the target.
Move up one step, let $C$ be the distance to the target.

So the target is located at $(x,y)$ with
$$\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 &= A^2 \\
(x-1)^2 + y^2&=B^2 \\
(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2&=C^2 
\end{align}$$

Subtracting the first equation from the second and the second equation from the first.

$$\begin{array}{rll}
A^2-B^2 &=
x^2 + y^2 -
\left((x-1)^2 + y^2\right) &=2x-1 \\
B^2-C^2 &= (x-1)^2 + y^2 - \left((x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2\right)&=2y-1
\end{array}$$

Therefore
$$\begin{align}
x &= \frac{1+A^2-B^2}2 \\
y &= \frac{1+B^2-C^2}2
\end{align}$$

Go Robot Go!

Comment: sorry.. my bad. I retired what I've said